# Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL" - None found - Angular2+

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am attempting to test an http get for my auth function but I'm having no luck.

I have been looking at [this resource](http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/mocking-http-request-with-httpclient-in-angular) and adapting for my own purposes but I am getting the error back:

> Error: Expected one matching request for criteria "Match URL: http://localhost:80001/...", found none.

I have attempted wrapping in an `async` but with no luck either.

**UPDATE**

On advice of @trichetriche, I moved my `apiBaseUrl` declaration into the actual class as to be referred to with `this.apiBaseUrl`, however running the test I am still getting the same error...

**UPDATE 2**

It appears my main problem was mis-typing the uri as 80001 instead of 8001. However I am now experiencing a new error:

> Cannot read property 'next' of undefined

**FINAL UPDATE**
The above error was being caused by the `async` wrapper I had added previously, and was brought on by the `q` dependency. Having removed the `async` all is running smoothly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means the two URLs aren't matching, and it happens because you are calling your endpoint in a bizarre way :

```
const apiBaseUrl = 'http://localhost:8001/data/betting/ui-api/v1';
```

Where is this declared ? Why isn't it a member of the service class ?

Comment: declare your URL as a member of your service, and use `this.apiBaseUrl` in your http calls.

Comment: Which service class are you referring to? It is currently part of the auth.service class... Or do you mean have it as part of what is exported?

Comment: If it's part of the AuthService, then why is it declared as a constant ? It's not possible to do that if it's part of a class.

Comment: Moved the `apiBaseUrl` declaration inside of the `export class AuthService {...}` but I am still getting the same error on my test :-/

Comment: You're missing a zero in your test URL. `80001` becomes `8001`.

Comment: My advice : if you ever run into this error again, run a search in your spec file with the actual URL. If you get no match, you mistyped your URL.

Comment: Ah, such a n00b move on my part, apologies.
However, now I have amended the uri, I am getting a different error: `Cannot read property 'next' of undefined`

Comment: It's not because of the URL, it's either because of an interceptor or because of a subject. Please poste your whole stack trace in your question.

Comment: Aha! It was being caused by the `async` I added but hadn't removed in my code. Caused by the `q` dependency. All fixed now. You must be getting tired of me @trichetriche :P